# Postfix and database

Tags: linux, redhat, postfix-mta, mail-server, dovecot

I am about to install postfix/Dovecot in Redhat Linux server. After checking this link  http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/server/postfix.html, I knew that I had to install berkley database too.

But after checking softwares installed on the server, I found another DB SW installed.

Can I depend on another kind of databases other than the one required in the above link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the version of Red Hat, but I assume you use a version which is not so terribly old it does not have yum.

With

```
yum deplist postfix
```

you can list all the dependencies which postfix has in the RPM package. On my Fedora system, `libdb` is listed as a dependency, which is the Berkeley DB library and is sufficient for postfix.

When you install RPM's with yum, the dependencies are automatically resolved and everything which is required will be installed. Trust yum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

For some reasons we're gonna install via source code,

so I am depending on dependencies mentioned in my 1st message.

Reason behind this: we cannot make internet accessible by server and postfix's version in yum is old, so I downloaded needed versions and moved them to version.

I'll proceed in installing via source code, but please advice if you've alternate solution to transform source code to RPM ?

Using: RHEL 5.9

Comment: You will need the Berkeley DB libraries if you're gonna compile by yourself.
For installing rpm's you don't need an internet connection on the server. You can download the required rpm packages to your workstation, copy them to the server and install them with yum from the files. Or you can build your own repo inhouse which is quite easy.
To see how it is compiled, you can download the source rpm from redhat and install that on your development machine (installing a source rpm will install the sources and the SPEC file) and you can rebuild the rpm from that.

Comment: The postfix version in RHEL5 is not the latest, that's right. If you depend on features only found in later versions, then you might have to build it yourself. If you are only after the security updates, you may still go with the redhat rpm's; security fixes are usually backported (which is one of the huge benefits of a redhat subscription).